# How to set two keystore in one core java based application(under one main)

Tags: java

In the Core java application I am working, there are two different functionalities, both using different set of Queues to connect to the queue manager. I am suppose to configure both these to different keystore(currently they are using the same).

Is there any way one application(one main method calling both functionlities) can have two keystores set.

Comment: You can combine the two keytores into one by importing one into the other using the Java `keytool`. Or you can use different properties to set the keystores depending on the application and use those in application in question.

Comment: @Omoro, For the second suggestion, I am setting different keystore to different functionalities. One functionality works when I block the other. But both do not work at the same time.